# setInterval - How to preserve passed in variable

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I did some digging around on SO and could not find exactly what I am trying to achieve.

In simplistic terms I have a function like

```
function(){
   for(i=0;i<10;i++){
      setInterval(function(){ alert(i);), 1000)
   }
}
```

What I would expect is 10 setIntervals that would alert 1 to 10 every 1 second, what happens is it would alert 10 always since 'i' is 10 at the end of for loop. How do I pass 'i' to setInterval anonymous function so that I can preserve the value of i in setInterval?

Above was a simplistic version of my actual problem. I am actually trying to do this
var timers = [];

```
function(obj){
   //Clear any intervals
   for(i=0;i<timer.length;i++){
      clearInterval(timers[i]);
   }

   // Empty timers Array
   timers = [];

   for(i in obj){
      //My object from the dom. This guy is what I am trying to preserve
      my_obj = document.getElementById(i);
      if(obj[i] === "Something"){
         timers.push(setInterval(function(){
            my_obj.replace_class(["Something", "Otherthing"],"Something");
         }, 1000)
      }
   }
}
```

my_obj in the above code always refers to id = last 'i' in obj.

Do I make sense?

Comment: [Once again](http://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/1169519) ; ).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript infamous Loop problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion for already asked questions. I guess I did not understand what my actual problem was so there was no way for me to search for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick ;)

```
for(i = 1; i < 11; i++){
  (function(local_i){ 
    setInterval(function(){ console.log(local_i); }, 1000 * local_i)
  })(i);
}
```

Comment: The above code has "10 setIntervals that would alert 1 to 10 every 1 second". Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure, if you had missed something, the question is somewhat vague. Anyway, all the set intervals are "firing" at the same time, hence you will get ten `1`s, ten `2`s etc. Perhaps it's better to use `setTimeout()`? Though this might be intended behavior too.

Comment: The code I gave fires 10 setIntervals every 1 seconds but they will print out 1 to 10 every time because it keeps the i values in a local var.

Comment: Do you want to fire one setInterval every second for 10 seconds?

Comment: Your answer did the trick. I think this is all about understanding the fundamentals of Javascript, which I am still learning. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You must capture the variable in a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1741542). In your case this is

```js
function capture(x) {
    setInterval(function () {
        console.log(x);
    }, 1000);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    capture(i);
}
```

or

```js
function capture(my_obj) {
    var id = setInterval(function() {
        my_obj.replace_class(["Something", "Otherthing"],"Something");
    }, 1000);

    return id;
}

for (i in obj) {
    //My object from the dom. This guy is what I am trying to preserve
    my_obj = document.getElementById(i);
    if (obj[i] === "Something") {
         timers.push(capture(my_obj));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Both the answers are great. Thanks.